# How to target siblings with different class name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, target, siblings

How can target class="a-2" inside id="b" by clicking on class="a-1" also inside id="b"?

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="a-1"></div>
    <div class="a-2"></div>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <div class="b-1"></div>
    <div class="b-2"></div>
</div>
<div id="c">
    <div class="c-1"></div>
    <div class="c-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the `.a-2` in your code?

Comment: Do you mean --- How can you target class="**b-2**" inside id="b" by clicking on class="a-1" also inside id="b"?, because there is no class="**a-2**"

Comment: good point! :D I meant targeting .b-2 by clicking on .a-1. both inside #b. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can always go through the parent:

```
element.parentNode.querySelector('.a-2')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can select all sibling nodes by selecting all children of the parent of the clicked node and then filter out the node that is clicked.

```js
const el = document.querySelectorAll('div > div');

const siblings = function(el) {
  const nodes = el.parentNode.children;
  return [...nodes].filter(node => node !== el)
}

el.forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    siblings(this).forEach(node => {
      console.log(node.textContent)
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="a-1">a</div>
  <div class="b-2">b</div>
  <div class="c-2">c</div>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <div class="a-1">a</div>
  <div class="b-2">b</div>
</div>
<div id="c">
  <div class="a-1">a</div>
  <div class="b-2">b</div>
</div>
```